# How do I meet the Visual Studio requirements for the react native windows installation?

Tags: react-native, react-native-windows

I'm trying to install the necessary requirements for React native Windows. However, I'm having trouble with Visual Studio.

I have installed Visual Studio 2022 with the MSBuild tools, Desktop development with C++, and Universal Windows Platform development, but I'm still not meeting the requirements for some reason. In other words, it's failing. I tried installing numerous times, but it's still not working.

[image: Image of failing to meet requirements]

Comment: Maybe you have a lower version than 17.9 of Visual Studio installed?

Answer (score -1):

Installing React Native can sometimes be a bit tricky, especially when dealing with dependencies like Visual Studio.

Firstly, ensure that you've installed the correct components within Visual Studio. You mentioned installing MSBuild tools, Desktop development with C++, and Universal Windows Platform development, which are indeed essential. However, sometimes certain components might be missing or not installed properly.

**Here's a checklist to verify:**

**Repair Visual Studio Installation:**

Open Visual Studio Installer.
Click on the three dots (...) next to your Visual Studio version.
Select "Repair."
Follow the prompts to repair the installation.
Restart your system after the repair process finishes.

**Check Environment Variables:**

Verify that the necessary paths for Visual Studio tools are added to your system's environment variables.
Ensure that paths like MSBuild and VC++ are correctly set.

Windows SDK Check:

**Confirm that you have the correct Windows SDK installed.**
Refer to the React Native for Windows documentation for the recommended SDK version.
If needed, install or update the SDK accordingly.

Comment: Is this AI-generated?